# How to add third parameter in Laravel where clause array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am dynamically adding conditional where statements in Laravel Query Builder.

```
$whereClause = array(
                       $field_name1 => $field_value1,
                       $field_name2 => $field_value2,
                       $field_name3 => $field_value3
            );

 $factories = DB::table('factories')
                ->where($whereClause)
                ->orderBy('ipo', 'desc')
                ->paginate(15);
```

**The above working just fine**, the problem is that I need to add third pram `'like'` of where statement `->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search_text . '%')`  in the $whereClause array, how can I do that?

Comment: You can have several `where` statements in your query, use one for the `like` and other for your array.

Comment: I need to add in the same array, since there will be a large array.

Comment: Just add outside array... and don't waste time because you must do this.

Comment: if you append `[ 'name', 'like', "%$search_text%" ]` to your `$whereClause` array it should work.

Comment: @Vincent Decaux You are right but that will increase the query and function sizes considerably, since I have very large queries already, with 20 or so left joins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use another array if you want to use an operator. So, your array will look like this:

```
$whereClause = [
    $field_name1 => $field_value1,
    $field_name2 => $field_value2,
    $field_name3 => $field_value3,
    [$field_name4, 'like', '%something%']
]
```

Comment: Let me test this.